Listing tags on an ECR pull through cache
If I list the tags in an ECR repository that is configured as a Pull-Through Cache, will my client receive the full list of tags available from upstream or only the subset of tags that have already been cached?
(For context, say I'm setting up a dynamically-scaled Kubernetes cluster in AWS and want container images cached within the same data-centre, and also want to use "infra as code" with automation such as RenovateBot or Flux Image Automation to propose upgrades as soon as more recent image releases become available upstream. Do I need this automation to  explicitly scan upstream registries, or can it still scan for updates through the cache?)
